# Removing Databases in Recovery Pending Status after AG group was removed

Tags: sql-server-2012, hadr

I have removed a High Availability Group, disabled the option in sql configuration manager and restarted and I have also removed the Failover cluster components from windows and restarted.

Unfortunately the databases are marked as Recovery Pending on both servers.

I have attempted to drop them, but get this:

> Msg 3752, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   
> The database 'GEO' is currently joined to an availability group.  Before you can drop the database, you need to remove it from the availatility group.

I also tried to recovery the db with no success and also set it into emergency mode but cannot:

> The operation cannot be performed on database "GEO" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.

I even tried to brute force the server by stopping the engine and renaming the file to try to get it into suspect, but its still in recovery pending...  I cant re-enable the HADR settings as the windows cluster has been destroyed.

All systems catalogs are empty apart from sys.availability_replicas which has a reference to the other server (first time in a few years I wish I was back in the good old days when I could access system tables).

Any ideas how to get rid of these databases?

Answer (score 5):

To resolve this I had to recreate the whole Failover cluster, re-enable HA in the SQL Configuration manager and then I could set one of the db's to recover

Answer (score 1):

Pause the Availability Group node in Failover Cluster Manager, and then restart the SQL Server service on that node. The database will drop out of recovery pending mode and could be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove it from the Availability Group ,
you can find both tsql and poweshell scripts in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231120.aspx

**important!** You must be connected to the server instance that hosts the secondary replica from which the database is to be removed.

Comment: the availability group no longer existed as had been dropped

Answer (score -4):

I had similar problems, and this solved it

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET HADR OFF
DROP DATABASE dbname
```